# ansible - run handler only if any task in role changed

Tags: ansible, yaml, handler, roles

I created a handler to `reboot server` and I have a role which sets up the os with several configuration (around 6 tasks in this role) and I want to trigger `reboot server` handler only if any of the task in the entire role is changed and that too after completion of entire role.

I tried to put 'notify' at the playbook for the role. but got error that `ERROR! 'notify' is not a valid attribute for a Play`

site.yml

```
---
- name: Setup OS parameters
  hosts: master_servers
  roles:
    - os_prep
  tags: os_prep
  notify:
    - restart server
```

handler to reboot server

```
---
- name: restart server
  command: /sbin/shutdown -r now
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  ignore_errors: true
  notify:
    - check server status

- name: check server status
  wait_for:
    port: 22
    host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    search_regex: OpenSSH
    delay: 10
    timeout: 60
  connection: local
```

After running the entire role 'os_prep', if any of the task in the role has 'changed' status, then `restart server` handler to be triggered.

Comment: Its fixed by calling handler from all the tasks that requires server reboot and seems the handler is getting triggered only once in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `notify` is an attribute for a task, not for a play. So you should add `notify: restart server` to all your tasks of your role. Let's say all your tasks are in `roles/os_prep/tasks/main.yml`. It would look like something like this:

```
---
- name: Configure this
  template:
    src: myConfig.cfg.j2
    dest: /etc/myConfig.cfg
  notify: restart server

- name: Change that
  moduleX:
    …
  notify: restart server

- name: Add users
  user:
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    home: "/home/{{ item.key }}"
    uid: "{{ item.value.uid }}"
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
  notify: restart server

- …
```

The behavior of the handler will proceed like you expect. If any of those tasks get the `changed` status, it will run the reboot (only once) at the end of the play.

Note that according to me you should not apply the `notify` to the task that don't need a reboot. Usually only few stuffs need a server reboot. In my example here above adding user don't need a reboot afterward. And most of the time a service restart will be enough. But of course, I don't know your use-case.

---

### Extra comments

#### Note 1

I see that you chain your handlers. Be aware that you could also use the `listen` attribute of handlers to do so. In you task you rather `notify: Restart and wait server`, and your `roles/os_prep/handlers/main.yml` will look like this:

```
---
- name: restart server
  command: /sbin/shutdown -r now
  async: 0
  poll: 0
  ignore_errors: true
  listen: Restart and wait server

- name: check server status
  wait_for:
    port: 22
    host: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
    search_regex: OpenSSH
    delay: 10
    timeout: 60
  connection: local
  listen: Restart and wait server
```

#### Note 2

Please be aware that there is a `reboot` module too that you could use in place of the `command: shutdown -r`.

Here is the doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html