# What is the best way to deal with Ansible's import_tasks/import_role and "notify"?

Tags: ansible, code-duplication, ansible-role

Here is a very simple code fragment taken from my "kafka" role:

```
- import_role:
    name: java
  notify:
    - restart kafka
    - restart zookeeper
```

Basically I want to install Java running "java" role and when there are changes performed by that role (e.g. Java has been updated), then restart "kafka" and "zookeeper" services. It turns out, Ansible doesn't throw any error as well as not running these handlers specified in "notify" field.

What would be my options to workaround this?

P.S. Java is being installed manually, not from repositories.

Comment: Ooops, duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542223/ansible-run-handler-only-if-any-task-in-role-changed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ansible - run handler only if any task in role changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542223/ansible-run-handler-only-if-any-task-in-role-changed)

Comment: Not really. I want to see what options do I have since my problem is very straightforward. The other thread is literally asking why it doesn't work, and I am asking what are my alternatives.

Comment: This is exactly the question you said was a duplicate an hour ago...

Comment: Nevermind, I answered my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

---

**Problem**

I have 3 roles in total:

- `kafka` - installs *kafka* and *zookeeper* apps, configures, enables/starts services etc.
- `ssl` - copies certificates to the server specific dir and that's it. When certificate is changed, I need to restart **only** kafka service.
- `java` - installs java and that is it. When java is updated, I need to restart **both** kafka and zookeeper services.

Then intention was to run only `kafka` role and include other `ssl` and `java` roles inside `kafka` role. Like this:

```
- import_role:
    name: java
  notify:
    - restart kafka
    - restart zookeeper

- import_role:
    name: ssl
  notify:
    - restart kafka
```

I've been expecting above code to work, because why not? Ansible did not throw any error regarding this, but silently did not run any handlers...

Note: both `ssl` and `java` are being re-usable roles, used by few other roles/playbooks.

---

**Workaround**

I've changed my handlers in `kafka` role into like this:

```
- name: restart kafka
  service:
    name: kafka
    state: restarted
  when: "'kafka_all' in group_names"
  listen:
    - restart SSL dependent services
    - restart java dependent services
    - restart kafka & zookeeper services

- name: restart zookeeper
  service:
    name: zookeeper
    state: restarted
  when: "'kafka_all' in group_names"
  listen:
    - restart java dependent services
    - restart kafka & zookeeper services
```

Then changed code in `kafka` role tasks like this:

```
- import_role:
    name: java

- import_role:
    name: ssl
```

And in both `java` and `ssl` role tasks I've added handlers accordingly. Like this for `ssl` role:

```
- name: upload SSL files
  copy:
    src: <hidden>
    dest: <hidden>
  notify: restart SSL dependent services
```

All above code might not make any sense yet, but familiarize yourself with below key points:

1. In `kafka` role I `import` and not `include` other roles. It means that imported roles (`kafka` and `ssl`) are able to "see" handlers of `kafka` role. [Upstream note](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_role_module.html).
2. I am using [Ansible's 2.8 new feature called `listen`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change). It means tasks can call a specified "listener" and it will automatically calls all listening handlers. If there are no handlers bound to the listener, it will not run anything (and that's expected behavior).
3. Not so important, but I am using `when: "'kafka_all' in group_names"` just because I am storing kafka installation tasks in task file `install.yml` and I specified there `notify: restart kafka & zookeeper services` and the thing is - I want to install Kafka on server where I want Kafka as a service as well as on server where I want to have Kafka CLI tools only (so no services are started). Such server won't be part of `kafka_all` and eventually these handlers won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this post and wishes for something aside from workarounds. I have found through some testing and research that one should be able to now have `notify:` work in `import_role:`. As of Ansible `v2.11` it appears that `notify:` is no longer ignored in the case of `import_role:`, meaning, the handlers specified as part of the `import_role:` task will run in the event said role does happen to make a change.

This seems to be an indirect benefit of now (at least as of Ansible `v2.11`) being able to add `notify:` to `block:` and `notify:` also not being ignored by `import_tasks:` (see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blame/stable-2.11/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.11.rst#L879 and https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/73572/commits).